# public role restrictions on a shared server prevent IntelliSense from working

Tags: sql-server, ssms, intellisense

I have an SQL Server 2016 database. This database is hosted on a **shared** server, and is managed by a central DBA team. In an effort to harden data security on the Production server, the DBA team has taken the approach to revoke/disable all public roles (i.e. DENY everything to the public role).

I believe this was done to limit (meta)data access to *other* databases on the same server, presumably along these lines: [Is it best practice to revoke server permissions to the server "public" role on SQL Server instances?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220225/is-it-best-practice-to-revoke-server-permissions-to-the-server-public-role-on)

The problem is that this setup prevents IntelliSense from working on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I think it's the situation Aaron Bertrand cautions on here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116814/180921

I have elevated access rights (RWED) to my database, but am not a full admin (this role is restricted to members of the DBA Production team).

**Is there a possible solution here? How can IntelliSense be made to work on my database, while respecting DBA desire to limit metadata view for *other* databases**

Comment: Exactly what are your elevated access rights to your database?

Comment: Sounds like they've denied read access to system tables for *this* database, also you shouldn't need to `DENY` just `REVOKE`

Comment: @DanGuzman I am a member of the Admin AD group. This group has: db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin, public, rd_execute

Comment: @Charlieface It's possible they used REVOKE rather than DENY. They said they in order to harden database servers "we have to Revoke/Disable all public roles in PROD".

Comment: @Roberto, I think you need db_owner to ignore the public DENY.

Comment: db_owner won't ignore DENY.  Only the _real_ dbo ignores permission checks.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, you're right, should have said dbo.

Comment: @DanGuzman @David Browne - Microsoft if I understood correctly, asking for db_owner rights won't do it. Does that mean I'm back to needing modifications on the `public` role? Is there a setup that will let me see metadata (IntelliSense) on my DB, without forcing IT to expose same for all the other databases on the server?

Comment: @Roberto, your choices are either to change the database owner to your login (`ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::YourDatabase to Roberto;`) or remove DENY to public on your database's system objects. The database-scoped public role does applies only to your database, not the other databases on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

The DBA Production team was finally able to solve this! They did not make changes to the `public role`, but rather they implemented some specific permissions to specific users/groups:

```
grant execute on xp_regread to [USER_ACCOUNT_TO_ENABLE_ON]
grant execute on xp_qv to [USER_ACCOUNT_TO_ENABLE_ON]
grant execute on xp_instance_regread to [USER_ACCOUNT_TO_ENABLE_ON]
grant execute on xp_msver to [USER_ACCOUNT_TO_ENABLE_ON]
```